# Use same, looked-up value across multiple linq Where clauses without looking up more than once

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query which has three `Where` clauses.  In each `Where` clause I am looking up the same set of items in order to compare values:

```
var items = _umbracoHelper.GetPage(ItemsPage.ModelTypeAlias).Children
                .Where(x => level1Category == 0 || x
                                .GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(UmbracoAlias.Item.Categories)
                                .Select(y => y.Id).Contains(level1Category))
                .Where(x => !level2Categories.Any() || x
                                .GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(UmbracoAlias.Item.Categories)
                                .Select(y => y.Id).Intersect(level2Categories.AsEnumerable()).Any())
                .Where(x => !level3Categories.Any() || x
                                .GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(UmbracoAlias.Item.Categories)
                                .Select(y => y.Id).Intersect(level3Categories.AsEnumerable()).Any());
```

Is there a way I can get the value of UmbracoAlias.Items.Categories once and store that value to be used in the other where clauses without causing the GetPropertyValue method to execute more than once?

Comment: Remove ".Contains(level1Category)" then you will get a list of all levels.  Then search the results.  You could put results into a dictionary so it would be faster to lookup any level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pair up each item with category IDs, like this:

```
var items = _umbracoHelper.GetPage(ItemsPage.ModelTypeAlias).Children
    .Select(c => new {
        Child = c
    ,   CategoryIds = c
           .GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(UmbracoAlias.Item.Categories)
           .Select(y => y.Id)
           .ToList()
    })
    .Where(x => level1Category == 0     || x.CategoryIds.Contains(level1Category))
    .Where(x => !level2Categories.Any() || x.CategoryIds.Intersect(level2Categories.AsEnumerable()).Any())
    .Where(x => !level3Categories.Any() || x.CategoryIds.Intersect(level3Categories.AsEnumerable()).Any())
    .Select(x => x.Child);
```

This does the filtering on children paired up with their category IDs, and then keeps only the `Child` object in the final projection.

You could further simplify this by combining all three `Where` clauses:

```
var items = _umbracoHelper.GetPage(ItemsPage.ModelTypeAlias).Children
    .Where(c => {
        var categoryIds = c
           .GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(UmbracoAlias.Item.Categories)
           .Select(y => y.Id)
           .ToList();
        if (level1Category != 0 && !categoryIds.Contains(level1Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (level2Categories.Any() && !categoryIds.Intersect(level2Categories.AsEnumerable()).Any()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (level3Categories.Any() && !categoryIds.Intersect(level3Categories.AsEnumerable()).Any()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: By the way, typo in the second example.  Needs semicolon after ToList()